# Any way to transfer custom data from Revit to Viewer?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Can I somehow transfer any custom data from the Revit model to the Forge Viewer (for example, a string)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. It is easy, and the possibilities unlimited. Check out my samples showing how to [connect desktop and cloud components](https://github.com/jeremytammik/FireRatingCloud), exemplified using Revit BIM on the desktop side and the Forge viewer and other web services on the cloud side.